# What image type and resolution is ideal for a logo inside of a Android Mobile Application?

Tags: interface-design, android, file-format, file-size

I have a png of a logo I am trying to import into my Android Application. However, it is looking extremely pixelated when I import it into my mobile app. The image is 538px by 113 px with a resolution of 72.

I have the vector of the image. I am just placing that vector into photoshop and then saving it as a png.

The image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0b2bb1t0960jr7z/logo.gif?dl=0

The view in the mobile app:

[image]

What dimensions, resolution, format type, Android xml traits, or programs should I use so that the image comes in clearer in the application?

Comment: The image doesn't look much worse to me than the dropbox linked image? Do you still have the working file for the logo? I would re-export the image with higher quality settings. If PNG, use PNG-24

Comment: There is no 'ideal' size other than make sure you use it at *actual* size in your app. If your logo is 538px wide, make sure it's 538 pixels wide in your app. If you need to support retina and other high-resolution screens, be sure to accommodate that as well.

Comment: @DA01 how would you be able to support retina or high resolution screens?

Comment: If your image is 100px wide, for a 2x screen, you'd need a version that is 200px wide. For a 3x screen, 300px wide, etc.

Comment: The *ideal* and future-proof option is `Vector Drawables`. They only work on the latest devices at the moment, though one or two years is likely to change that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When developing in Android, keep in mind that different devices have different screen sizes and screen densities. If you're using Android Studio, when you import the image as a resource to your project, you should be prompted about the different densities of the image (low, medium, high, etc.). It could be possible that your development environment activity is at a different density than your actual device (assuming you are building to the device from the screenshot attached), or expects a different resolution than your image.

Also, if you are displaying the image using an ImageView, check the 'ScapeType' property and see if it's causing the image to appear differently than desired.

[More information on supporting different screen sizes in Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

[More information on ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)